# Returning distance and Searching by radius in Solr 1.5

Tags: solr, distance, spatial

Does anyone know of a means of returning the distance in the result set using Solr 1.5?  An example of the function we're using is: dist(2, store, vector(43.517030,-96.789603)) where "store" is a LatLon field containing both latitude and longitude of each item in the index.  Can you give an example URL that would return a distance field in the results?

We're currently using the nightly build dated the day of this posting.

Answer (score 0):

Solr cannot currently return distance, yet bizarrely it can sort by distance. ANyway, all you need to do is to return the latlng and then do the maths to work out distance by yourself.